# Using sed, i want to replace the the string value in a file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

```
cat input2.txt
```

Output:

```
    'enable_lb': True,
    'enable_firewall': True,
    'enable_vpn': True,
```

I tried

```
sed "s/^*.enable_firewall.*/    'enable_firewall': False,/" input2.txt
```

It's not changing the value of firewall to false, please help me out in this syntax

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `.` before the `*`, so that it would match any char zero or more times.

```
sed "s/^.*enable_firewall.*/    'enable_firewall': False,/" input2.txt
```

To do an in-place edit, add `-i` parameter.

```
sed -i "s/^.*enable_firewall.*/    'enable_firewall': False,/" input2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise:

```
sed "s/\('enable_firewall': \)True/\1False/g" file
```

This matches exactly `'enable_firewall': True`

Or:

```
sed "s/\('enable_firewall':.*\)True/\1False/g" file
```

This matches `enable_firewall':*True` * means anything

Or:

```
sed "s/\('enable_firewall':[ \t]*\)True/\1False/g" file1
```

This matches `'enable_firewall': True` with zero or more spaces or tabs between `:` and `True`. If at least one space is a must, use `[ \t]\+` instead of `[ \t]*`

Note: use `sed -i ...` to replace inplace in file